# Changing duplicate values in a column to null in SQL

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying to build a database for school that builds the flight plans for aircraft at a company (Tables Flight, Manifest, and Configuration).  I was able to get all the tables to populate correctly except for the configuration table.  Right now it reuses the aircraft, pilot, co-pilot, attendant1, and attendant2 for each flight out of a specific location.  Instead I want it to only use each 1 time and mark all the other values as null if there are not additional things to support that flight.

Current Example:

| FlightID | AcftID | PilotID | PilotName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 1 | Tom Cruise |
| 2 | 1001 | 1 | Tom Cruise |
| 3 | 1002 | 2 | Bob Cruise |
| 4 | 1002 | 2 | Bob Cruise |
| 5 | 1003 | 3 | Sam Cruise |

What I want:

| FlightID | AcftID | PilotID | PilotName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 1 | Tom Cruise |
| 2 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 1002 | 2 | Bob Cruise |
| 4 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | 1003 | 3 | Sam Cruise |

Ideally, I would like to do this by changing the Status In the Aircraft or Aircrew table to flying but if that is not possible I would just want to process these changes after the configuration table is built.

Here is my code

```
CREATE DATABASE Project;
USE Project;
-- Create 7 Tables for holding the data
CREATE TABLE Locations(
    LocationName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LocationCode VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE Aircraft (
    AcftID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Status VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Location VARCHAR(50),
    Capacity INT NOT NULL,
    ARange INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(Location) REFERENCES Locations(LocationCode)
);
CREATE TABLE Aircrew (
    AircrewID INT NOT NULL,
    AircrewName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Position VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Location VARCHAR(50),
    StatUpdate INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(AircrewID, AircrewName),
    FOREIGN KEY(Location) REFERENCES Locations(LocationCode)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_Aircrew_AircrewName ON Aircrew (AircrewName);
CREATE TABLE Passenger (
    PassID INT NOT NULL,
    PassName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Ticket INT NOT NULL,
    StartLoc VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    EndLoc VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(PassID, PassName, Ticket, StartLoc, EndLoc),
    FOREIGN KEY(StartLoc) REFERENCES Locations(LocationCode),
    FOREIGN KEY(EndLoc) REFERENCES Locations(LocationCode)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_Passenger_PassName ON Passenger (PassName);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_Passenger_Ticket ON Passenger (Ticket);
CREATE TABLE Flight (
    FlightID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    StartLoc VARCHAR(50),
    EndLoc VARCHAR(50),
    FRange INT NOT NULL,
    PCount INT NOT NULL,
    Depart TIME NOT NULL,
    Land TIME NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (StartLoc) REFERENCES Passenger(StartLoc),
    FOREIGN KEY (EndLoc) REFERENCES Passenger(EndLoc)
);
CREATE TABLE Configuration (
    FlightID INT,
    AcftID INT,
    PilotID INT,
    PName VARCHAR(50),
    CPilotID INT,
    CPName VARCHAR(50),
    AttendID1 INT,
    AttendName1 VARCHAR(50),
    AttendID2 INT,
    AttendName2 VARCHAR(50),
    FOREIGN KEY (FlightID) REFERENCES Flight(FlightID),
    FOREIGN KEY (AcftID) REFERENCES Aircraft(AcftID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PilotID) REFERENCES Aircrew(AircrewID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PName) REFERENCES Aircrew(AircrewName),
    FOREIGN KEY (CPilotID) REFERENCES Aircrew(AircrewID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CPName) REFERENCES Aircrew(AircrewName),
    FOREIGN KEY (AttendID1) REFERENCES Aircrew(AircrewID),
    FOREIGN KEY (AttendName1) REFERENCES Aircrew(AircrewName),
    FOREIGN KEY (AttendID2) REFERENCES Aircrew(AircrewID),
    FOREIGN KEY (AttendName2) REFERENCES Aircrew(AircrewName)
);
CREATE TABLE Manifest (
    FlightID INT,
    Ticket INT,
    PassID INT,
    PassName VARCHAR(50),
    FOREIGN KEY (FlightID) REFERENCES Flight(FlightID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Ticket) REFERENCES Passenger(Ticket),
    FOREIGN KEY (PassID) REFERENCES Passenger(PassID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PassName) REFERENCES Passenger(PassName)
);
-- Insert data into the tables
INSERT INTO Locations (LocationName, LocationCode)
VALUES
  ('Austin', 'AUS'),
  ('Dallas Fort Worth', 'DFW'),
  ('El Paso', 'ELP'),
  ('Houston (George Bush)', 'IAH'),
  ('San Antonio', 'SAT');
INSERT INTO Aircraft (AcftID, Status, Location, Capacity, ARange)
VALUES
    (1001, 'Available', 'AUS', 150, 4),
    (1002, 'In Maintenance', 'DFW', 180, 5),
    (1003, 'Available', 'ELP', 120, 3),
    (1004, 'Flying', 'IAH', 200, 6),
    (1005, 'Available', 'SAT', 100, 2),
    (1006, 'Available', 'DFW', 160, 4),
    (1007, 'In Maintenance', 'SAT', 140, 3),
    (1008, 'Available', 'AUS', 130, 3),
    (1009, 'Available', 'DFW', 180, 5),
    (1010, 'Flying', 'IAH', 200, 6);
INSERT INTO Aircrew (AircrewID, AircrewName, Status, Position, Location, StatUpdate)
VALUES
  (1, 'John Smith', 'Available', 'Pilot', 'AUS', 0),
  (2, 'Emily Williams', 'Flying', 'Pilot', 'IAH', 3),
  (3, 'William Davis', 'Crew Rest', 'Pilot', 'SAT', 0),
  (4, 'James Taylor', 'Available', 'Pilot', 'AUS', 0),
  (5, 'Emma Anderson', 'Unavailable', 'Pilot', 'DFW', 8),
  (6, 'Charles Thomas', 'Flying', 'Pilot', 'SAT', 2),
  (7, 'Richard Lewis', 'Unavailable', 'Pilot', 'SAT', 10),
  (8, 'Andrew Young', 'Flying', 'Pilot', 'AUS', 5),
  (9, 'David Hernandez', 'Unavailable', 'Pilot', 'ELP', 9),
  (10, 'Joseph Green', 'Flying', 'Pilot', 'IAH', 1),
  (11, 'Jane Doe', 'Unavailable', 'Co-Pilot', 'DFW', 6),
  (12, 'Robert Brown', 'Available', 'Co-Pilot', 'ELP', 0),
  (13, 'Olivia Martinez', 'Flying', 'Co-Pilot', 'AUS', 4),
  (14, 'Samantha Allen', 'Available', 'Co-Pilot', 'DFW', 0),
  (15, 'Alexis Moore', 'Crew Rest', 'Co-Pilot', 'IAH', 0),
  (16, 'Madison King', 'Available', 'Co-Pilot', 'SAT', 0),
  (17, 'Michael Johnson', 'Crew Rest', 'Co-Pilot', 'ELP', 0),
  (18, 'Abigail Lee', 'Available', 'Co-Pilot', 'DFW', 0),
  (19, 'Natalie Hall', 'Crew Rest', 'Co-Pilot', 'AUS', 0),
  (20, 'Jennifer Scott', 'Flying', 'Co-Pilot', 'SAT', 7),
  (21, 'William Smith', 'Available', 'Flight Attendant', 'AUS', 0),
  (22, 'Ava Johnson', 'Unavailable', 'Flight Attendant', 'DFW', 6),
  (23, 'Oliver Davis', 'Flying', 'Flight Attendant', 'ELP', 3),
  (24, 'Sophia Wilson', 'Available', 'Flight Attendant', 'IAH', 0),
  (25, 'Lucas Brown', 'Crew Rest', 'Flight Attendant', 'ELP', 0),
  (26, 'Isabella Martin', 'Available', 'Flight Attendant', 'DFW', 0),
  (27, 'Mia Lee', 'Unavailable', 'Flight Attendant', 'SAT', 10),
  (28, 'Alexander Clark', 'Flying', 'Flight Attendant', 'AUS', 5),
  (29, 'Charlotte Perez', 'Available', 'Flight Attendant', 'DFW', 8),
  (30, 'Amelia Mitchell', 'Crew Rest', 'Flight Attendant', 'ELP', 0),
  (31, 'Harper Roberts', 'Available', 'Flight Attendant', 'IAH', 0),
  (32, 'Evelyn Turner', 'Unavailable', 'Flight Attendant', 'IAH', 0),
  (33, 'Mason Phillips', 'Flying', 'Flight Attendant', 'DFW', 0),
  (34, 'Ella Rodriguez', 'Available', 'Flight Attendant', 'SAT', 0),
  (35, 'Carter Lewis', 'Crew Rest', 'Flight Attendant', 'AUS', 0),
  (36, 'Scarlett Adams', 'Available', 'Flight Attendant', 'DFW', 0),
  (37, 'Grayson Hernandez', 'Flying', 'Flight Attendant', 'ELP', 0),
  (38, 'Lily Foster', 'Unavailable', 'Flight Attendant', 'IAH', 0),
  (39, 'Michael Campbell', 'Available', 'Flight Attendant', 'ELP', 0),
  (40, 'Grace Gomez', 'Crew Rest', 'Flight Attendant', 'SAT', 0);
INSERT INTO Passenger (PassID, PassName, Ticket, StartLoc, EndLoc)
VALUES
  (1, 'John A. Smith', 10001, 'DFW', 'IAH'),
  (2, 'Emma B. Johnson', 10002, 'AUS', 'DFW'),
  (3, 'Michael C. Williams', 10003, 'SAT', 'DFW'),
  (4, 'Olivia D. Davis', 10004, 'ELP', 'SAT'),
  (5, 'William E. Brown', 10005, 'IAH', 'ELP'),
  (6, 'Sophia F. Lee', 10006, 'AUS', 'IAH'),
  (7, 'Liam G. Martinez', 10007, 'DFW', 'AUS'),
  (8, 'Isabella H. Taylor', 10008, 'SAT', 'IAH'),
  (9, 'Noah I. Anderson', 10009, 'ELP', 'AUS'),
  (10, 'Ava J. Garcia', 10010, 'IAH', 'ELP'),
  (11, 'James K. White', 10011, 'DFW', 'AUS'),
  (12, 'Emily L. Rodriguez', 10012, 'SAT', 'DFW'),
  (13, 'Jackson M. Martinez', 10013, 'ELP', 'SAT'),
  (14, 'Mia N. Smith', 10014, 'IAH', 'ELP'),
  (15, 'Abigail O. Brown', 10015, 'AUS', 'IAH'),
  (16, 'Ethan P. Johnson', 10016, 'DFW', 'AUS'),
  (17, 'Charlotte Q. Williams', 10017, 'SAT', 'ELP'),
  (18, 'Amelia R. Taylor', 10018, 'ELP', 'IAH'),
  (19, 'Harper S. Anderson', 10019, 'IAH', 'DFW'),
  (20, 'Evelyn T. Garcia', 10020, 'DFW', 'ELP'),
  (21, 'Liam U. Brown', 10021, 'SAT', 'AUS'),
  (22, 'Sophia V. Johnson', 10022, 'ELP', 'IAH'),
  (23, 'Jackson W. Davis', 10023, 'AUS', 'ELP'),
  (24, 'Olivia X. Smith', 10024, 'IAH', 'DFW'),
  (25, 'Aiden Y. Taylor', 10025, 'DFW', 'SAT'),
  (26, 'Emma Z. Lee', 10026, 'SAT', 'AUS'),
  (27, 'Charlotte A. Garcia', 10027, 'ELP', 'IAH'),
  (28, 'Liam B. Smith', 10028, 'AUS', 'ELP'),
  (29, 'Ava C. Johnson', 10029, 'IAH', 'DFW'),
  (30, 'Noah D. Davis', 10030, 'DFW', 'AUS'),
  (31, 'Evelyn E. Smith', 10031, 'SAT', 'ELP'),
  (32, 'James F. Martinez', 10032, 'ELP', 'IAH'),
  (33, 'Sophia G. Johnson', 10033, 'IAH', 'DFW'),
  (34, 'Oliver H. Williams', 10034, 'DFW', 'SAT'),
  (35, 'Isabella I. Davis', 10035, 'SAT', 'AUS'),
  (36, 'Mia J. Smith', 10036, 'ELP', 'DFW'),
  (37, 'Liam K. Lee', 10037, 'AUS', 'IAH'),
  (38, 'Charlotte L. Anderson', 10038, 'IAH', 'ELP'),
  (39, 'Emma M. Martinez', 10039, 'DFW', 'AUS'),
  (40, 'Olivia N. Taylor', 10040, 'SAT', 'DFW'),
  (41, 'Aiden O. Johnson', 10041, 'ELP', 'AUS'),
  (42, 'Evelyn P. Garcia', 10042, 'IAH', 'ELP'),
  (43, 'Sophia Q. Smith', 10043, 'AUS', 'IAH'),
  (44, 'Liam R. Davis', 10044, 'DFW', 'SAT'),
  (45, 'Ava S. White', 10045, 'SAT', 'ELP'),
  (46, 'Oliver T. Williams', 10046, 'ELP', 'DFW'),
  (47, 'Emma U. Taylor', 10047, 'IAH', 'AUS'),
  (48, 'Amelia V. Brown', 10048, 'AUS', 'ELP'),
  (49, 'Harper W. Garcia', 10049, 'DFW', 'SAT'),
  (50, 'Evelyn X. Lee', 10050, 'SAT', 'ELP'),
  (51, 'Ethan Y. Smith', 10051, 'ELP', 'IAH'),
  (52, 'Charlotte Z. Anderson', 10052, 'AUS', 'DFW'),
  (53, 'Ava A. Martinez', 10053, 'IAH', 'ELP'),
  (54, 'Noah B. Taylor', 10054, 'DFW', 'SAT'),
  (55, 'Emma C. Johnson', 10055, 'SAT', 'AUS'),
  (56, 'Oliver D. Brown', 10056, 'ELP', 'DFW'),
  (57, 'Sophia E. Davis', 10057, 'IAH', 'ELP'),
  (58, 'Liam F. Smith', 10058, 'AUS', 'DFW'),
  (59, 'Evelyn G. Garcia', 10059, 'DFW', 'SAT'),
  (60, 'Aiden H. Johnson', 10060, 'SAT', 'ELP'),
  (61, 'Emma I. Taylor', 10061, 'ELP', 'IAH'),
  (62, 'Charlotte J. Garcia', 10062, 'IAH', 'DFW'),
  (63, 'Olivia K. Davis', 10063, 'DFW', 'SAT'),
  (64, 'Liam L. Smith', 10064, 'SAT', 'AUS'),
  (65, 'Evelyn M. Garcia', 10065, 'ELP', 'DFW'),
  (66, 'Emma N. Johnson', 10066, 'IAH', 'ELP'),
  (67, 'Aiden O. Davis', 10067, 'AUS', 'IAH'),
  (68, 'Sophia P. White', 10068, 'DFW', 'SAT'),
  (69, 'Olivia Q. Taylor', 10069, 'SAT', 'ELP'),
  (70, 'Liam R. Johnson', 10070, 'ELP', 'DFW'),
  (71, 'Evelyn S. Garcia', 10071, 'IAH', 'AUS'),
  (72, 'Emma T. Smith', 10072, 'DFW', 'ELP'),
  (73, 'Charlotte U. Brown', 10073, 'SAT', 'IAH'),
  (74, 'Oliver V. Anderson', 10074, 'ELP', 'AUS'),
  (75, 'Ethan W. Garcia', 10075, 'IAH', 'ELP'),
  (76, 'Sophia X. Davis', 10076, 'AUS', 'IAH'),
  (77, 'Liam Y. Smith', 10077, 'DFW', 'ELP'),
  (78, 'Aiden Z. Taylor', 10078, 'SAT', 'DFW'),
  (79, 'Emma A. Johnson', 10079, 'ELP', 'AUS'),
  (80, 'Charlotte B. Brown', 10080, 'IAH', 'ELP'),
  (81, 'Olivia C. Davis', 10081, 'DFW', 'IAH'),
  (82, 'Evelyn D. Martinez', 10082, 'AUS', 'SAT'),
  (83, 'Sophia E. White', 10083, 'ELP', 'DFW'),
  (84, 'Liam F. Taylor', 10084, 'IAH', 'ELP'),
  (85, 'Emma G. Garcia', 10085, 'DFW', 'AUS'),
  (86, 'Dustin H. Johnson', 10086, 'SAT', 'IAH'),
  (87, 'Oliver I. Smith', 10087, 'ELP', 'SAT'),
  (88, 'Ethan J. Williams', 10088, 'IAH', 'DFW'),
  (89, 'Charlotte K. Anderson', 10089, 'AUS', 'ELP'),
  (90, 'Emma L. Davis', 10090, 'SAT', 'AUS'),
  (91, 'Sophia M. Taylor', 10091, 'ELP', 'IAH'),
  (92, 'Liam N. Smith', 10092, 'IAH', 'SAT'),
  (93, 'Evelyn O. Garcia', 10093, 'DFW', 'ELP'),
  (94, 'Aiden P. Johnson', 10094, 'AUS', 'DFW'),
  (95, 'Olivia Q. Davis', 10095, 'ELP', 'SAT'),
  (96, 'Emma R. Taylor', 10096, 'IAH', 'DFW'),
  (97, 'Charlotte S. Brown', 10097, 'AUS', 'ELP'),
  (98, 'Sophia T. White', 10098, 'SAT', 'DFW'),
  (99, 'Oliver U. Williams', 10099, 'ELP', 'IAH'),
  (100, 'Ethan V. Smith', 10100, 'IAH', 'AUS');
-- Create Flights from passenger requirements and insert into flight data
INSERT INTO Flight (FlightID, StartLoc, EndLoc, FRange, PCount, Depart, Land)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StartLoc, EndLoc) AS FlightID,
    StartLoc,
    EndLoc,
    1 + RAND() * 4 AS FRange,
    COUNT(*) AS PCount,
    SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR(RAND() * 43200)) AS Depart,
    0 AS Land
FROM Passenger
GROUP BY StartLoc, EndLoc;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE Flight
SET Land = DATE_ADD(Depart, INTERVAL FRange HOUR);
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
-- Create Manifest table based on Flight and Passenger start and end location
INSERT INTO Manifest (FlightID, Ticket, PassID, PassName)
SELECT
    F.FlightID,
    P.Ticket,
    P.PassID,
    P.PassName
FROM
    Flight F
JOIN
    Passenger P ON F.StartLoc = P.StartLoc AND F.EndLoc = P.EndLoc;
-- Create Configuration table based on Flight, Aircraft location and availability, and Aircrew position, location, and availability
INSERT INTO Configuration (FlightID, AcftID, PilotID, PName, CPilotID, CPName, AttendID1, AttendName1, AttendID2, AttendName2)
SELECT
    F.FlightID,
    A.AcftID,
    (
        SELECT AircrewID FROM Aircrew 
        WHERE Location = F.StartLoc AND Position = 'Pilot' AND Status = 'Available'
        ORDER BY StatUpdate ASC LIMIT 1
    ) AS PilotID,
    (
        SELECT AircrewName FROM Aircrew 
        WHERE Location = F.StartLoc AND Position = 'Pilot' AND Status = 'Available'
        ORDER BY StatUpdate ASC LIMIT 1
    ) AS PName,
    (
        SELECT AircrewID FROM Aircrew 
        WHERE Location = F.StartLoc AND Position = 'Co-Pilot' AND Status = 'Available'
        ORDER BY StatUpdate ASC LIMIT 1
    ) AS CPilotID,
    (
        SELECT AircrewName FROM Aircrew 
        WHERE Location = F.StartLoc AND Position = 'Co-Pilot' AND Status = 'Available'
        ORDER BY StatUpdate ASC LIMIT 1
    ) AS CPName,
    (
        SELECT AircrewID FROM Aircrew 
        WHERE Location = F.StartLoc AND Position = 'Flight Attendant' AND Status = 'Available'
        ORDER BY StatUpdate ASC LIMIT 1
    ) AS AttendID1,
    (
        SELECT AircrewName FROM Aircrew 
        WHERE Location = F.StartLoc AND Position = 'Flight Attendant' AND Status = 'Available'
        ORDER BY StatUpdate ASC LIMIT 1
    ) AS AttendName1,
    (
        SELECT AircrewID FROM Aircrew 
        WHERE Location = F.StartLoc AND Position = 'Flight Attendant' AND Status = 'Available'
        ORDER BY StatUpdate ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
    ) AS AttendID2,
    (
        SELECT AircrewName FROM Aircrew 
        WHERE Location = F.StartLoc AND Position = 'Flight Attendant' AND Status = 'Available'
        ORDER BY StatUpdate ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
    ) AS AttendName2
FROM
    Flight F
JOIN
    Aircraft A ON F.StartLoc = A.Location
WHERE
    A.Capacity >= F.PCount;

SELECT * FROM Configuration;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ROW_NUMBER() function to rank the data and assign NULL to data which rank is not 1.

```
UPDATE Flights AS f
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        FlightID,
        AcftID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AcftID ORDER BY FlightID) AS rn1,
        PilotID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PilotID ORDER BY FlightID) AS rn2
    FROM Flights
) AS subquery
ON f.FlightID = subquery.FlightID
SET 
    f.PilotID = CASE WHEN subquery.rn2 = 1 THEN subquery.PilotID ELSE NULL END,
    f.AcftID = CASE WHEN subquery.rn1 = 1 THEN subquery.AcftID ELSE NULL END;
```

At first, a subquery is generated which is like this:

```
FlightID    AcftID  rn1 PilotID rn2
1           1001    1       1   1
2           1001    2       1   2
3           1001    3       2   1
4           1001    4       2   2
5           1002    1       3   1
6           1002    2       3   2
7           1002    3       4   1
8           1002    4       4   2
9           1003    1       4   3
10          1003    2       5   1
```

Then, when rn1 is not equal to 1, AcftID is set to NULL. similarly, when rn2 is not equal to 1, PilotId is set to NULL.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I am not currently in front of my computer with SQL but would this also work for rows that contain strings rather than variables as well?

Comment: This approach numbers rows as 1, 2, 3 and so go based on how you order the data. So works for all types of variables

Comment: When I tried that I got the error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'AcftID' in 'field list'

I am updating the original question so that you can see everything in context.  I am taking my first SQL class, using MySQL Workbench, right now so I am still somewhat green.  All of my tables work correctly except the Configuration one which I only want to select each item (ACFT, Pilot, Co-Pilot, Attendant1, Attendant2) once.  Ideally if I could change the status of each item to Flying after they are chosen that would be even better.  Thanks for your help.